# Allow only emails to access site where logos are (Django)

Tags: django, user-permissions

I have a page `mysite.com/logos` containing images. I want to be able to link to those images in my emails when sending out news-letters (instead of attaching them), but I don't want users (or others) to be able to access them. Right now people can just go to "mysite.com/logos" - I would prefer that'll throw an 403/404 error for all users trying to access `mysite.com/logos`, but being able to include the images in my emails.

Comment: "_I want to be able to link to those emails_" which _emails_ are you talking about here exactly? Do you perhaps mean to say you want to limit a certain page to certain _users_?

Comment: Sorry, a typo. I have made an edit to explain it further

Comment: Do you mean your server returns directory listing? You should configure the webserver if that's the case. You can not just forbid users to copy-paste the content.